# boost::unordered_map missing reserve() like std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map, boost-unordered

For my next task I need to use a very big hash; since I have an old compiler I cannot use C++0x `std::unordered_map`. Ideally I need is a call to `reserve` to make room in advance for a large number of items. I cannot find this method in `boost::unordered_map`: is there any place or function that achieves the same?

The 2 associative container are the same; I can see `rehash` function and the same constructor for controlling the number of buckets, but not a function about a number of elements.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reserve` can be emulated by `rehash` as in Table 103 in N3376.

```
a.rehash(n) 
Post: a.bucket_count() > a.size() / a.max_load_factor() 
      and a.bucket_count() >= n.

a.reserve(n) Same as a.rehash(ceil(n / a.max_load_factor()))
```

Comment: @ pmr: thanks for your response!! I was going to use a for cycle inserting empty data but I had too much luaghs thinking about this method!!:D