# initialize an STL `map` size

Tags: c++, dictionary

is it possible to initialize an STL `map` size?

I know how many elements will be in my map at the end and I want to allocate all the required memory at the very beginning.

Comment: Which usage pattern do you have? Do you have any deletes? Or it is just initial fill, and then usage without change?

Comment: I need to initialize with zeros and then increment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options:

- You may try to use map with statefull allocator. For instance from [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/container/Cpp11_conformance.html#container.Cpp11_conformance.alloc_traits_move_traits) or from C++11. Or if you accept limitations of non-statefull allocators, then you could even use map from C++98/03.
- Consider to use unordered_map (again from Boost or from C++11) - it takes buckets count as constructor parameter. It differs from map, in that it is based on hashing rather than on strict weak ordering.
- Another option is flat_map from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html). It has **reserve** member function. [Description](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) of flat map/set:

> Boost.Container flat_[multi]map/set containers are ordered-vector based associative containers based on Austern's and Alexandrescu's guidelines

- Or, if boost is not available - then you could simply use std::vector + std::sort + std::lower_bound (or wrap them to small flat_map like class). I.e. just put your elements to vector (unordered), then sort it, and then - when you need to query element by key - just use lower_bound.

Which choice is better - depends on your usage patterns.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. It's a tree (usually a red-black tree). The actual values are going to determine memory layout.

**However**, you ***can***

- use [Boost Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) maps (which use elements you allocated in another container, like a vector), decorated with 'hooks' to implement the map functionality over it
- use std::map with allocators, so you can allocate all the actual elements from a fixed 'pool' (memory region)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to use its iterator constructors.  The only trick there is that then you have to create *another* container with the size you need, and give its iterators to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`reserve` can be emulated by `rehash` as in Table 103 in [N3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf).

```
a.rehash(n) 
Post: a.bucket_count() > a.size() / a.max_load_factor() 
      and a.bucket_count() >= n.

a.reserve(n) Same as a.rehash(ceil(n / a.max_load_factor()))
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618264/489590)

Comment: That's for `std::unordered_map<>`, not `std::map<>`.